# how to print numbers in ARMv8

Tags: c, assembly, arm, printf, armv8

I have the following ARMv8 code for a program that prints to stdout a count of how many lines, words, and characters it has read from a given input file:

```
            .section        .data
lLineCount:     .quad   0
lWordCount:     .quad   0
lCharCount:     .quad   0
iInWord:        .quad   0

        .section        .text
        .global        main

main:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        mov     x29, sp
        adrp    x0, lLineCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lLineCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        ldr     x0, [sp, 16]
        bl      getchar
        cmp     x0, #-1
        b.eq    .L2
        adrp    x0, lCharCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lCharCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        add     x1, x1, 1
        str     x1, [x0]
        adrp    x0, iInWord
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:iInWord
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        cmp     x1, 0
        b.ne    .L3
        adrp    x0, lWordCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lWordCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        add     x1, x1, 1
        str     x1, [x0]
        mov     x0, 0
        str     x0, [x0]
        b       .L4

.L3:
        adrp    x0, lWordCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lWordCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        add     x1, x1, 1
        str     x1, [x0]
        mov     x0, 0
        str     x0, [x0]

.L4:
        adrp    x0, lLineCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lLineCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        add     x1, x1, 1
        str     x1, [x0]
        b       .L1

.L2:
        adrp    x0, lLineCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lLineCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        ldr     x0, [sp, 16]
        bl      printf
        mov     x0, 0
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
        ret

.L1:
        adrp    x0, lLineCount
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:lLineCount
        ldr     x1, [x0]
        ldr     x0, [sp, 16]
        bl      getchar
        cmp     x0, #-1
        b.ne    .L3
```

How can I get it to print out the values of lLineCount, lWordCount, lCharCount? How do I print such values in ARMv8, and where would I put said print command? At the moment, when I am testing this program, nothing is being printed to stdout.

Your help is much appreciated as I am new to ARM and am still learning.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect `ldr x0, [sp, 16]` to do. In any case, `printf` needs a format string, so define an appropriate one and pass its address.

Comment: AArch64 has 32 registers, use 3 of them instead of global variables for your counts.  (Pick call-preserved registers so `getchar` won't overwrite them.)  That would tighten up your code a *lot* removing all those `adrp` and `ldr` / `str` instructions.  Is this unoptimized compiler output?  If you're using a compiler and library functions, put `printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", bytes, words, lines);` in your source and compile that.

Comment: @PeterCordes i am required to keep global variables for the counts. Quick question for you: when compiling and testing my armv8 program above with a given input text file, I get a segmentation fault. Any ideas on what might be causing this and how exactly I can fix it?

Comment: You can probably just store to the globals after updating registers, not also loading from them all the time.  Ideally just update them after the loop, unless your assignment requires inefficient code.  As for the segfault, run your code under a debugger to see which instruction faults.  Like `gdb` or `lldb`. If it's in a library function, check on the args you passed to it and on stack alignment.  If it's in your own code, look at registers as you single-step up to the point where it crashes.

Comment: armv8 has no printing capabilities (see pdp8 as an example of something that does).  if you are trying to make a function call or a system call then the question you are asking is the calling convention for the library or operating system you are using.